# deleting a huge matrix after passing its local copy to a function in Matlab

Tags: matlab, function, memory-management

Considering we have a huge matrix called A and we pass it to the function func(A) wherein `func` I do a set of computations like:

```
func(A):

B=A;

%% a lot of processes will happen on B here 

return B;

end
```

The fact is that as soon as I pass A to B I would not have anything to do with A anymore in my Matlab session so it takes an unnecessary space in memory. Is it possible to remove its instance in the scope of the script that called `func`?

Answer (score 4):

Using [evalin](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/evalin.html) with the option `caller` you can evaluate expression `clear A`:

```
function A = func(A)
    evalin('caller', 'clear A')
    A(1) = 5;
end
```

However we usually don't know the name of the input variable so we can use [inputname](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inputname.html) to get the actual name of the workspace variable:

```
function A = func(A)
    name = inputname(1);
    if ~isempty(name)
        evalin('caller', ['clear ' name])
    end
    A(1)=4;
end
```

1.Here `inputname(1)` means the actual name of the first argument.

2.Work directly with `A` because if you copy `A` into `B` the function scope will have two copies of `A`.

Comment: Yes, you can do this, but what a surprise if I use the function as `B=func(A); mean(A);`! I would be **very** careful with `evalin` and `assignin`.

Comment: You are right , although there are some workarounds for such conditions.

Answer (score 4):

If you write your function as

```
function A = func(A)
% Do lots of processing on A here
```

and call it as

```
A = func(A);
```

Then MATLAB will optimize it such that you work on A in-place, meaning that no copy is made. There is no need to delete A from the workspace.

This behavior is not expressly documented as far as I know, but it is well-known. See for example on [Undocumented MATLAB](https://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/internal-matlab-memory-optimizations), or on [Loren's blog](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2007/03/22/in-place-operations-on-data/).

Comment: Interesting! Is this behavior documented anywhere?

Comment: @rahnema1 Here is a MathWorks blog explaining the behaviour https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2007/03/22/in-place-operations-on-data/ it was a "relatively recent optimisation" when written in 2007, so is perhaps even more robust now.

Comment: I have added two links to the answer, included the one suggested by @Wolfie . Thanks!